# Symfony 2 update data on export

Tags: php, symfony, export, backend, sonata-admin

I have backend on SonataAdminBundle 2.4.*@dev version.

Before update version and symfony core from 2.7 to 2.8 my code worked.

Explain:
I have an list of subscribers that have a flag **isNew** for separate export of new or old users. By default is 1, on export need to change it to 0 if in list exist new users.

But now it doesn't work. Because if filter of grid is set by this field isNew and export, in DB field is changed before, and later

```
return $this->get('sonata.admin.exporter')->getResponse(
        $format,
        $filename,
        $this->admin->getDataSourceIterator()
    );
```

getDataSourceIterator take data from DB not from result. So there is no more new users and file is empty.

How to update data after export, have any idea?

UPDATE:

Export function:

```
/**
 * Export data to specified format.
 *
 * @param Request $request
 *
 * @return Response
 *
 * @throws AccessDeniedException If access is not granted
 * @throws \RuntimeException     If the export format is invalid
 */
public function exportAction(Request $request = null)
{
    $request = $this->resolveRequest($request);

    $this->admin->checkAccess('export');

    $format = $request->get('format');

    $allowedExportFormats = (array) $this->admin->getExportFormats();

    if (!in_array($format, $allowedExportFormats)) {
        throw new \RuntimeException(
            sprintf(
                'Export in format `%s` is not allowed for class: `%s`. Allowed formats are: `%s`',
                $format,
                $this->admin->getClass(),
                implode(', ', $allowedExportFormats)
            )
        );
    }

    $filename = sprintf(
        'export_%s_%s.%s',
        strtolower(substr($this->admin->getClass(), strripos($this->admin->getClass(), '\\') + 1)),
        date('Y_m_d_H_i_s', strtotime('now')),
        $format
    );


    //my code to update field isNew of subscribers
    $this->get('cfw.subscription')->processExportEmails($controller->admin->getFilterParameters());

    return $this->get('sonata.admin.exporter')->getResponse(
        $format,
        $filename,
        $this->admin->getDataSourceIterator()
    );
}
```

Comment: Can you please show me the whole function  (before the return) ?

Comment: it is bundle's function

Comment: sorry, I mistaked, it is bundle's function overrided

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found an solution, maybe someone know better, please post here. I solved by update data in listener onTerminate. Look code:

service config:

```
sonata.admin.subscription.listener:
        class: SiteBundle\Listener\ExportSubscriptionListener
        arguments: [@service_container]
        tags:
            - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: kernel.controller, method: onKernelController }
            - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: kernel.terminate, method: onKernelTerminate }
```

in controller I deleted overridden method exportAction() and added little method

```
/**
 * @return AdminInterface
 */
public function getAdmin()
{
    return $this->admin;
}
```

ExportSubscriptionListener:

```
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\FilterControllerEvent;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Controller\CRUDController;
use SiteBundle\Controller\SubscriptionAdminController;

class ExportSubscriptionListener
{
    /**
     * @var CRUDController
     */
    protected $controller;

    /**
     * @var ContainerInterface
     */
    protected $container;

    public function __construct(ContainerInterface $container)
    {
        $this->container = $container;
    }

    public function onKernelController(FilterControllerEvent $event)
    {
        $this->controller = $event->getController();
    }

    /**
     * Update new subscribers on export
     */
    public function onKernelTerminate()
    {
        $controller = $this->controller[0];

        if (!$controller instanceof SubscriptionAdminController) {
            return;
        }

        if ($this->controller[1] !== 'exportAction') {
            return;
        }

        //here we update in service data
        /** $var SubscriptionAdminController $controller */
        $this->container->get('service.subscription')->processExportEmails($controller->getAdmin()->getFilterParameters());
    }
}
```

and update of data in service:

```
/**
 * @param array $subscriptions
 */
public function processExportEmails(array $filterParameters)
{
    $criteria = [];

    if(!empty($filterParameters['locale']) && $filterParameters['locale']['value'] !== "") {
        $criteria['locale'] = $filterParameters['locale']['value'];
    }

    if(!empty($filterParameters['new']) && $filterParameters['new']['value'] !== "") {
        $criteria['new'] = $filterParameters['new']['value'];
    }

    $subscriptionRepository = $this->getRepositorySubscription();

    $subscriptions = null;
    if (count($criteria) > 0) {
        $subscriptions = $subscriptionRepository->findBy($criteria);
    } else {
        $subscriptions = $subscriptionRepository->findAll();
    }

    /** @var array|null $subscriptions */
    foreach ($subscriptions as $subscription) {
        /** @var Subscription $subscription */
        if ($subscription->isNew()) {
            $subscription->setNew(false);
            $this->getEntityManager()->persist($subscription);
        }
    }

    $this->getEntityManager()->flush();
}
```